# Reason for error and solution -"undefined reference to `newwin' "?

Tags: c

I am compiling a program which creates window on shell. When I compile I get errors like

```
test.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `newwin'
test.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `wborder'
test.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
..
..
```

One of my functions is

```
WINDOW *f_top, *f_bottom;
WINDOW *create_window(int n, int d, char *t){
        WINDOW *frame;
        WINDOW *w;
        frame = newwin(n, COLS, d, 0);
        box(frame,0,0);
        mvwprintw(frame,0,COLS/2-strlen(t)/2,t);
        wrefresh(frame);
        w = newwin(n-2, COLS-2, d+1, 1);
        idlok(w, TRUE);
        scrollok(w, TRUE);
        wclear(w);
        wrefresh(w);
        return w;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link with the curses library. The functions are defined there.

Try

```
gcc ... test.c ... -lcurses ...
```

or maybe

```
gcc ... test.c ... -lncurses ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more explicit,

Firstly you need to install the curses (or ncurses) library if required.

Secondly, include curses.h

Thirdly, these need to be found, you may have issues with the $PATH.

Finally, depending on how much later this is being read, there may be 'deprecated' functions.
- search curses.h (and then the web) for the the names.

Typically for a 64 bit Linux installation, the assets involved might be found in :

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so

/usr/include/curses.h